# Is Olingo4 backward compatible?

Tags: java, rest, odata, olingo

If I use Olingo4 libraries at client side (java), would they be compatible with ODATA 2.x services?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

The long answer is, Olingo or any other library is just an implementation of the OData Protocol. The version 4 of the protocol had breaking(read incompatible) changes, with the previous versions.

You can check out [this link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.0/cn01/new-in-odata-v4.0-cn01.html) to get a list of all changes, including the incompatible ones in OData 4.

Now to be fully compatible, with both OData 2 and OData 4, you can read the `OData-MaxVersion` header sent by the client and based on it, you can send the response accordingly.This will require you to have both odata 2 and odata 4 implementations(using Olingo 2 and Olingo 4 or something else) running on your backend.

On a personal note, if you are starting out today and don't have a strong reason to have two implementations, it's not mandatory for an OData v4 service to support a lower version client.

An OData 4 service may respond to V1-V3 clients with 4XX-level errors.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398370

Answer (score 1):

It may work in some trivial scenarios, but even a simple `count` option differs much for different OData versions:

1. http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/Products/?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json [v2]
2. http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$count=true&$format=json [v4]

[Official OData page](http://www.odata.org/libraries/) suggests that *Apache Olingo*, *odata4j* and *Jello Framework* should have client implementations for OData 2. I've not worked with Olingo's client for v2, but I've heard it is very poor. And I couldn't find anything interesting from *odata4j* or *Jello Framework* (quick research).

In the worst scenario, you can go with a standard HTTP client. In the end, OData is based on REST.